# How do I stop powershell from watching a file for a few seconds?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'm writing something in powershell to watch file 'A' for changes and open file 'B' when it does. The only problem is the excel file (B) has vba code to run on open that has to copy over the data on file 'A.' From my research it seems like I have to open file 'A' to do this since it has to be a .xlsx and opening it starts a continuous loop.

I've tried the sleep command, but it seems like it's still watching the file during or before the sleep, and then just opens the file again once it has waited the amount of time I tell it.

How do I make the watcher stop watching for just a minute or so?

Here is the code I'm working with currently:

```
    Function Register-Watcher {
    param ($folder)
    $filter = "*.xlsx"
    $folder = "\\powershell\watcher\test\folder"

    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true


    }

    $changeAction = [scriptblock]::Create('

        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

        Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"

        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Excel.Workbooks.Open("\\powershell\watcher\test\folder\fileB.xlsm")
        sleep 60

    ')

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action $changeAction
}

 Register-Watcher "\\powershell\watcher\test\folder\fileA.xlsx"
 $Change
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop it from raiseing events using

```
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
```

You can read more about it here from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.enableraisingevents?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_FileSystemWatcher_EnableRaisingEvents

Comment: This is working to cut off the loop, but once the changeAction occurs, it leaves the script incapable of raising events. I have tried disabling raising events and sleeping for a few seconds, but resetting $watcher.enableraisingevents = $true afterwards doesn't seems to re-enable the script.

Comment: where are you putting the $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false and True in the script?

Comment: The $false seemed to work right after the #excel.workbook.open so I went with that and then sleep 10 then setting raising events to $true. Is this incorrect?

Comment: why are you sleeping?

Comment: I think looking at your post code that you have the wrong engineering Idea. Looks like you are trying to call maybe the $watcher from inside that changeAction script block

Comment: I assumed the VBA may need time to run and open the other workbook. I tested it without and it does the same thing- it opens the file B like its meant to, but if I edit file A for a second time it does nothing.

Comment: See the watching isnt just a single thread. The watcher starts script blocks in a seprate thread. The sleep is only effecting the thread the script started in. The watcher is still kicking off actions because its not in the same thread. Make any sense? This means the scriptBlock cant talk to the watcher

Comment: I am, I need to open file B when file A is changed and then let file B open file A without triggering the watcher again. That said, I want the watcher to be able to be triggered afterwards. Okay so how do I set events to $false right after the change action and then set it to true a few moments after?

Comment: Read over my last comment and tell me if that makes any sense. You cant stop the watcher from inside the scriptblock

Comment: So yes, that makes sense. Is there an alternative? Like an if, while, or do statement in the object that sets EnableRaisingEvents to false for a few seconds after the scriptblock has run? Or can they just not reference each other at all?

Comment: I dont think they can reference at all but i could be wrong. Just wanted to point out its a engineering problem not a code problem

Comment: Well thanks for the help, I have a much better understanding on whats happening now.